# How to pass a variable to search context?

Tags: jss, graphql

I have created a SearchContext, defined query, provider etc. I have a variable to pass so can get result depending on what is being passed.

Now, how do I pass this `$query` variable (which will be a Sitecore field) to SearchContext Provider in JSS so that SearchContext Consumer can get the result set?

If I don't put any such condition then all works fine I get all the records.

Any help will be appreciated.

[image: This is the search query I want]

Comment: You mean how you would populate the $query from your front end to the graphql?

Comment: @HishaamNamooya field value is in a sitecore field. I would like to send that value as a query.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using ReactJs, you can from your component implementation pass a value to the query. Please see below code snippet where part of it is taken from the ReactJs sample provided by JSS.

```
import { loader as gqlLoader } from 'graphql.macro';
import GraphQLData from '../../lib/GraphQLData';
import { withSitecoreContext } from "@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-react";

const ConnectedDemoQuery = gqlLoader('./query.graphql');
...
//component implementation goes here.
...
const wrappedComponent = withSitecoreContext()(props => {
  const WrappedComponent = compose(
    GraphQLData(ConnectedDemoQuery, {
      name: "connectedQuery",
      options: {
        variables: {
          query: "Your value goes here"
        }
      }
    })
  )(GraphQLConnectedDemo);
  return <WrappedComponent />;
});

export default withSitecoreContext()(wrappedComponent);
```

From the above code snippet, the `query` variable is where you specify the value you want to pass to the GraphQL. Note that in this example I've used the `withSitecoreContext`. This helps to provide more context of the current site.

Moreover, the `compose` method enables you to execute more than 1 GraphQL query.

Note, if you are using either Angular or ReactJs, you can see how connected GraphQL works by creating a sample project using the JSS CLI. More information is available at [JSS Documentation](https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/getting-started/quick-start).

Comment: Thanks for the reply @WalidRohiman  this is another way of doing it, I'm sure I can use it for different propose. But for now  I'm trying to implement it using React.createContext();. I created Search provider </SearchContext.Provider> and using Search Consumer to display.