# How to pass query variables in graphql

Tags: jss, graphql, nextjs

I couldn't find a way to pass query variables to my graphql query, I've made a query which I think is how I'd be able to do mutation

```
mutation UpdateItem($datasource: String!, $language: String!, $fields: String!) {
  updateItem(
    path: $datasource
    language: $language
    fields: $fields
 ){
 ... on SampleItem {
     title {
      value
     }
    }
   }
 }
```

but I couldn't figure out how to pass my query variables.

I found this in the stackexchange [How to pass a variable to search context?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/25661/how-to-pass-a-variable-to-search-context) but I couldn't find the GraphQLData library

Any enlightenment on this matter would be greatly appreciated, Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you check this - https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables

Comment: Did above link resolves your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are trying it with GraphQL GUI and my understanding is that the question is how to pass a query variable dynamically to the query or mutation.

Here I'm trying to update the Title field value of Home item with following code.

```
mutation UpdateItem($datasource: String!,$language: String!, $fields: [FieldValueInput!]) {
  updateItem(
        path: $datasource,
      language: $language, 
        fields: $fields){
    ... on SampleItem {
      title {
        value
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Query variable:

```
{
  "datasource":"/sitecore/content/home",
  "language":"en",  
  "fields": [{ 
        "name": "title",
        "value": "'Example Item with changed title'"
      }]
}
```

It will look like this in GraphQL Playgrond.
[image]

Also you can check the schema by clicking `Docs` button at the right side. The API documentation tab is one of the most exciting features of GraphQl Playground. It enables you to preview GraphQL queries, GraphQL type details, and a single field of a given schema.

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response, sorry I thought this question was hidden by the admin/bots due to duplicate question. My intended question was passing query variables from code to sitecore graphql, I have found a way via fetch api though I wanted to implement it the same way it is structured in the styleguide graphql integrated sample docs, nevertheless your answer is valid so I will mark it as answered, thanks!